# Query Link for Retrofit

Tags: java, android, rest, get, retrofit

First post, so sorry if my terminology is unclear.

So I'm using retrofit to GET an array of objects from a link: *BASE_URL*/**todos?userId=1**.
When using:

```
@GET("todos?userId={userId}")
Call<List<ToDoObject>> listTodos(@Query("userId") int userId);
```

for this retrofit call:

```
 retrofit.Retrofit retrofit = new retrofit.Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        BaseServiceAPI service = retrofit.create(BaseServiceAPI.class);
        Call<List<ToDoObject>> listToDos = service.listTodos(getUserId());

        listToDos.enqueue(new Callback<List<ToDoObject>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<List<ToDoObject>> response, retrofit.Retrofit retrofit) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++) {
                        toDoObjectList.add(response.body().get(i));
                    }
                    toDoRecycAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else Log.d("flow", "no go");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.d("flow", "todo failure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

to get this array:

```js
[
  {
    "completed": false,
    "dueDate": "2016-07-31 06:38:00",
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Find your son Duke",
    "userId": 1
  },
  {
    "completed": false,
    "dueDate": "2017-05-24 07:30:00",
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Rule the City ",
    "userId": 1
  },
  {
    "completed": true,
    "dueDate": "2016-1-30  1:15:00",
    "id": 6,
    "title": "Run The ",
    "userId": 1
  },
  {
    "completed": true,
    "dueDate": "2016-1-30  1:28:00",
    "id": 7,
    "title": "Hmmm",
    "userId": 1
  }
]
```

I receive this error: "FATAL EXCEPTION: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "userId={userId}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query."

I thought this was the proper case to use Query. I even tried Path but still nothing. I don't know many other programmers to ask and I've been at this for weeks. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please??

Thanks in advance

Comment: just remove `?userId={userId}` from `@GET("todos?userId={userId}")`

Comment: If i do that then I get a list of ALL of the items, and I need only the items specific to that userID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just leave @Query parameter in your request and remove it from @GET. Also you say that you need to request only specific object, so why your response contains the list `Call<List<ToDoObject>>`?

```
@GET("todos")
Call<ToDoObject> specificTodo(@Query("userId") int userId);
```

Comment: OMG! You are the best! I assumed that if I queried a parameter that I had to include it in the URL. I can't thank you enough @Roman C